# Can method references be used to access static methods?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

According to:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

It looks like its possible, however trying it for real returns a compile error.
It makes more sense that it shouldn't be possible as we cannot implement interfaces with static methods.

```
public class SomeClass {

    static public boolean getB(){
        return false;
    }
}

List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();       
list.add(new SomeClass());

// below causes compile error, which I expect, however documentation indicates oherwise
list.stream().filter(SomeClass::getB).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is the compile error:

"Multiple markers at this line
    - The method getB() from the type SomeClass should be accessed in a static way
    - The method filter(Predicate) in the type Stream is not applicable for the 
     arguments (SomeClass::getB)"

Comment: Add the compile error?

Comment: What is `list`??? Where is it declared?

Comment: Maybe it caused by signature incompatibility. `filter`expects lambda has one parameter and returns boolean. And you try to use method without parameters

Comment: @nnesterov it works if I remove static which does not affect the method signature

Answer (score 6):

You can, but the return type and arguments of the method must match the ones of the unique method of the functional interface (`Predicate<Something>` here).

Assuming your list is a `List<Something>`, since the predicate is supposed to return a boolean based on a `Something` as input, your code will compile if your method is defined as

```
public static boolean getB(Something s)
```

or

```
public static boolean getB(Object o)
```

Comment: Because in this case, the method is called on each SomeClass instance of the stream being filtered. The input of the predicate is the SomeClass instance itself (i.e. `this`). The method reference, written as a lambda, in case of a static method is `sc -> SomeClass.getB(sc)`, and in case of an instance method is `sc -> sc.getB()`.

Comment: Why does SomeClass::getB work in any case? getB does not match the Predicate interface

Comment: It does when it has a SomeClass as input, and a boolean as output. The point of a method reference is to be able to express a lambda such as `sc -> SomeClass.foo(sc)` by just using `SomeClass::foo`. The name of the method doesn't matter.

Comment: So there is some magic behind the scenes, which I think doesn't make much sense, surely a method should only be take a input that matches its declared types in the signature. The only other case of this sort of behaviour is auto boxing of primitives, which I think is fine because its a simple primitive to object type conversion, changing method signatures is confusing.

Comment: It's not magic. It's well-defined specifications. And it feels quite intuitive and natural once you've used them for a while. You might think it doesn't make much sense, but it does, really.

Comment: It doesn't really save much typing over using the lambdas directly, and it adds complexity that I feel its not worth the reward, unless there is another advantage of using these that differs from simpler reducing typing by a few characters, if so could you provide examples please?

Comment: It generates less byte-code and, often, is more readable. I find `persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName).thenComparing(Person::getFirstName))` quite natural and readable. A bit more than `persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(person -> person.getLastName()).thenComparing(person -> person.getFirstName()))`. Even more for things like `reduce(Integer::sum)` rather than `reduce((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2)`.